# JMeter Recording Controller is not working

Tags: jmeter

I am using Apache JMeter 2.13. For recording step I have followed this link:
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

After following all these steps Recording Controller under test plan is not start recording. Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: It works for me in 2.13. Can you be more specific about not recording? Did you set up the proxy in your browser correctly? Is not the default 8080 port occupied by something else - try changing it. Are you recording HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: I have set up proxy in my browser and when I click on start button of 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder' it starts recording. But 'Recording Controller' under Thread Group not start recording.

Answer (score 6):

According to you, you have created "Thread Group" under "Test Plan" and you have created "Recording Controller" under "Thread Group".

Double check the following:

1. Go to "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" under "Workbench" and set the correct Target Controller at the right panel.
2. Start the "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" by clicking Start button at the bottom
3. In "HTTP Request Defaults" under "Thread Group": Input "Server Name or IP" correctly
4. Set up the browser proxy perfectly. (Default port in "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" of JMeter is 8080. Use the 8080 in the browser proxy also. If you want to change the proxy say, 9090 use the same proxy (9090) in the browser proxy set up)

Please see the image attached here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I noted a missing step in [the Test Script Recorder documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf). It may be obvious to some, but I didn't do it and it creates the exact situation above.

## You have to start the Test Script before you navigate to the website!

Otherwise the Thread Group is not started and neither is the Recording Controller. However the Test Script Recorder is working.

So the definitive steps would be (using @RiponAlWasim's list):

1. Setup the Test Script Recorder

   - Go to "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" under "Workbench" and set the correct Target Controller at the right panel.
   - Start the "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" by clicking Start button at the bottom
2. Setup the Recording Controler

   - In "HTTP Request Defaults" under "Thread Group": Input "Server Name or IP" correctly
   - Make sure only the Recoding Controller's Thread Group is active - We don"t want to inject transactions, just record what goes through the proxy.
   - Start the Test Script cby clicking the green Arrow "Start" in the main JMeter toolbar or by selecting "Run" -> "Start"
3. Set up the browser proxy perfectly. (Default port in "HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder" of JMeter is 8080. Use the 8080 in the browser proxy also. If you want to change the proxy say, 9090 use the same proxy (9090) in the browser proxy set up)

I'll see what I can do to fix the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it turned out that you can't use "localhost" as proxy server name. Using the PC's DNS name instead of "localhost" in the browser's proxy settings fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem my solution was to add Target test controller.
[image]